# Identical characters of a list count

Tags: excel, list, function

I am looking for a formula that compares elements of a list based on the following criteria per cell: are the first 5 digits the same with any other item of the list? Second task: Same, but with the last 5 digits. I tried it with left and right, but it didn't work. It should work as a filter and should give me a Yes or the number of cells with identical first 5 characters:

```
EAJKDH232DEW
JEDOEL234DMD
EAJKD3324HDF
```

In this case, a 2 or yes for the first an last item and a no or 1 for the middle one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have u tried so far?

Comment: I tried to build an excel function using something like LEFT5 but it is not working. I can use the filter to check, but that takes way too long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First 5 digits:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,LEFT(A1,5)&"*")
```

[image]

Last 5 digits:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,RIGHT(A1,5)&"*")
```